# how to find unmatched record from one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **student.**

```
id   | name | age | email | address
------------------------------
 1   | abc  | 20  | abc@gmail.com  |  street number10
------------------------------
 2   | def  | 25  | def@gmail.com  |  street number12
------------------------------
 3   | hjk  | 20  | hjk@gmail.com  |  street number10
------------------------------
 4   | umnnn  | 20  | umnn@gmail.com  |  street number10
```

I want to match rows and want unmatched record.

***Example:***

row 3rd(id=3) should be matched with row 4th (id=4) and should give only unmatched value of 4th row means value of id=4, name=umnn, email=umnn@gmail.com only, not should be age and address.

row 2nd(id=2) should be matched with row 3rd (id=3) and should give only unmatched value of 3rd row means value of id=3, name=hkj, age=20, email=hkj@gmail.com, address=street number10.

and like this 1st and 2nd row should be matched and should be give value of 2nd row id,name,age,email only.

Comment: how can you say that 1st and 2nd match?

Comment: it is my question that to compare both row? Please tell me any clue.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using self join

```
select t1.id,case when t1.name!=t2.name then t1.name else NULL end as name 
       ,case when t1.age!=t2.age then t1.age else NULL end as age
       ,case when t1.email!=t2.email then t1.email else NULL end as email
       ,case when t1.address!=t2.address then t1.address else NULL end as address
from test t1
inner join test t2
on t1.id=t2.id+1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aad8d3/9)

Comment: it is useful, but it matches only last and second last rows. But i want all unmatched results for history. It should be match 2nd and 3rd row and so on. And please note: ID may be random like 1,5,9,10,23